# Adding a backslash to the end of a PHP string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm attempting to do a basic query in Laravel by querying a table that holds polymorphic relationships. The table has a column called `record_type` which holds values such as `App\MedicationError` and `App\PressureUlcer`.

I want to run a query similar to this:

```
`Action::where('record_type','App\MedicationError')`
```

I have a set of variables containing strings like `MedicationError` and `PressureUlcer`.

How would I go about prefixing those strings with `App\`?

The reason I am having difficulty myself is I cannot work out how to add a backslash to the end of my `'App'` string. This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
$type = 'App\\ '.studly_case($record->type);
```

But it returns  `App\\ RiskAssessmentUpdate`. If I remove the space from the end the backslash obviously escapes the single quote. `trim('App\\ ')` doesn't help either.

I feel like I'm missing a really obvious (regex?) solution here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use double slash it means that the first slash escapes the second one so 'App\\' will produce App\.

Comment: You need to escape the slash if it's enclosed in double quotes , i.e. `"\\"` you don't need to do that if it's enclosed in single quotes e.g. `'\'`

Comment: @apokryfos - au contraire, even in single quotes, certain characters need to be escaped; and `'\'` is one of those [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).... a single quote (`'`) inside a single-quoted string is another character that needs escaping

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually a `\ ` in a single quote does not need to be escaped. It's suprising but check the example in your linked page with command `echo 'You deleted C:\*.*?';`

Comment: I was simply going by the statement in the PHP Docs.... `To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\).` I think it all comes down to the character following the backslash, if it requires escaping; but I prefer to err on the side of caution

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP is weird sometimes

Answer (score 4):

Putting two backslashes together in a single quoted string should create a single backslash, the first one escapes the second.

```
$type = 'App\\' . studly_case($record->type);
```

Alternatively, you could use a double quoted string, in the same way:

```
$type = "App\\" . studly_case($record->type);
```

My guess is that your problem lies in the `studly_case($record->type)` part of your code, in that it's returning a backslash at the beginning of it. Give this code a try and see if it works:

```
$type = "App\\" . ltrim(studly_case($record->type), '\\');
```

That should trim off any and all leading backslash characters.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work. In both cases the query that was output just included two backslashes like `App\\PressureUlcer`

Comment: In that case, can you confirm that your `$record->type` does not begin with a backslash character?

Comment: It's actually set earlier in my code like this: `DB::raw('"Medication Error" as type')`

Comment: Try running `dd(studly_case($record->type));`. Does that output a string with a leading backslash? In any case, see my updated answer

Comment: No I'm afraid not. It returns: `"PressureUlcer"`

Comment: Ok I just tried `dd('App\\'.studly_case($record->type))` and it showed the correct string. So it looks like I was barking up the wrong tree. The issue must be with how I'm using the string after that (in DataTables output)